# jquery validation & clearing error messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form with 3 fields to be input, first name, last name, and email address.

The elements are all similar to this one that I've got for the email address:

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <label for="Email_Address">Email Address</label>
  </dt>
  <dd style="float:right">
     <input type="text" id="Email_Address" class="required  email" name="Email_Address" />
     <br>
     <span class="form_error" id="email_error">
       <span id="email_msg"></span>
     </span>
   </dd>
</dl>
```

The span below it, class "form_error" is where I'm displaying any validation errors.  The validation code all works fine, checking for a valid email address, etc.  Then I thought I would throw in an AJAX validation where I can check to see if that email address was already on file, and if it is, display a message too.  That all is fine.  The problem is if someone enters a email address that is already on file, and they get the message "email is already on file".  Then they go to change the email address in the form, and I get the validation error, but I can't seem to figure out how to clear out the "already on file" message.  I've tried using `empty()`, `replaceWith()`, and a few others, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the validation code, with the AJAX call.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm not quite an expert in all of this yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#LegalVita_Sign_Up").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var isDup = false;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'dup_email.php',
        data: { email: $('#Email_Address').val() },
        async: false, 
        success: function(msg) { 
          isDup = msg === "1" ? true : false 
        },
      });         

      if (isDup) {
        error = 'duplicate email address: ' + $('#Email_Address').val();
        $('#email_msg').replaceWith(error);
        return false;
      } else {
        form.submit();
        return true;
      }
    },
    messages: {
      First_Name: " First name required",
      Last_Name: " Last name required",
      Email_Address: {
        required: " email required",
        email: " email must be of the format: 'name@domain.com'"
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr("name") == "First_Name" )
        error.insertBefore("#first_msg");
      else if (element.attr("name") == "Last_Name" )
        error.insertBefore("#last_msg");
      else if (element.attr("name") == "Email_Address" ) {
        error.insertBefore("#email_msg");
      } else
        error.insertAfter(element);
},
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to jQuery Validate. Set `$('#email_msg').text('')` at the beginning of your submit handler.

Comment: That doesn't quite do it, as the validation fails, so the submit handler doesn't appear to get called.  Instead, I get the new validation error inserted before the old "duplicate email" message.
Like this: email requiredduplicate email address: lew@test.com

Comment: The call to $.ajax is asynchronous. You need to check for is_dup and submit the form in the success handler and not outside it. `if (msg === "1") { form.submit(); } else { <show error message> }`

Comment: That helped.  I also needed to put $('#email_msg').text('') at the beginning of the errorPlacement and then it works great.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: If my answer helped, be sure to accept it as it the right one.